# Excel in C# web app skips some headings and does not format

Tags: c#, silverlight, excel

I have a web app which reads an excel sheet and adds in 3 columns. Here i service code which reads and write columns.

For the date columns, it is not writing their heading, not any heading for the new columns.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;
using FDBService.AppCode;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace FDBService
{
                    vFileName = string.Concat(vPath, DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString().Replace(":", "").Substring(0, 6), "_", pUploadfile.fileName);
                FileStream FileStream = new FileStream(vFileName, FileMode.Create);
                FileStream.Write(pUploadfile.file, 0, pUploadfile.file.Length);
                FileStream.Close();
                FileStream.Dispose();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            return vFileName;
        }

        public List<Medicine> ProcessPriceList(string pFileName)
        {

            List<Medicine> lstReturn = null;
            string strConnection = string.Concat("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=", pFileName, ";Extended Properties=", "Excel 8.0;");
            System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable("dtSheet");
            try
            {
                using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(strConnection))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    System.Data.DataTable dtSheet = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                    List<string> lstSheet = new List<string>();
                    foreach (DataRow drSheet in dtSheet.Rows)
                    {
                        if (drSheet["TABLE_NAME"].ToString().Contains("$"))//checks whether row contains '_xlnm#_FilterDatabase' or sheet name(i.e. sheet name always ends with $ sign)
                        {
                            lstSheet.Add(drSheet["TABLE_NAME"].ToString());
                        }
                    }
                    using (OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + lstSheet[0] + "]", conn))
                    {
                        //////conn.Open();
                        da.Fill(dt);
                    }
                }

                if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    dt.Columns.Add("Unit Price", typeof(string));
                    dt.Columns.Add("Price", typeof(string));
                    dt.Columns.Add("Variance", typeof(string));
                    dt.Columns.Add("PercentVariance", typeof(string));

                    string vFDBPath = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FDBFilePath"].ToString();

                    FDB objFDB = null;
                    string[] strFDB = File.ReadAllLines(vFDBPath);
                    List<FDB> lstFDB = new List<FDB>();
                    foreach (string str in strFDB)
                    {
                        objFDB = new FDB();
                        objFDB.NDC = str.Substring(0, 11);
                        objFDB.PriceType = str.Substring(11, 2);
                        objFDB.Price = string.Concat(str.Substring(21, 6), ".", str.Substring(27, 5));
                        objFDB.Date = str.Substring(13, 8);
                        lstFDB.Add(objFDB);
                    }

                    double dPrice = 0;
                    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            string ndc = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i][7]);
                            List<FDB> objLst = (from item in lstFDB
                                                where item.NDC == ndc && item.PriceType == "09"
                                                orderby item.Date descending
                                                select item).ToList();
                            if (objLst != null)
                            {
                                FDB objFirstItem = objLst.FirstOrDefault();
                                if (objFirstItem != null)
                                {
                                    if (new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(objFirstItem.Date.Substring(0, 4)), Convert.ToInt32(objFirstItem.Date.Substring(4, 2)), Convert.ToInt32(objFirstItem.Date.Substring(6, 2))) > Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[i][6]))
                                    {
                                        if (objLst.Count > 1)
                                        {
                                            FDB objSecondItem = objLst[1];
                                            dt.Rows[i]["Unit Price"] = objSecondItem.Price;
                                            dPrice = Convert.ToDouble(objSecondItem.Price) * Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[i][13]);
                                            dt.Rows[i]["Price"] = dPrice;

                                            double billPrice = Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[i][12]);
                                            dt.Rows[i]["Variance"] = (billPrice - dPrice);
                                            if (dPrice != 0)
                                            {
                                                //////dt.Rows[i]["PercentVariance"] = string.Concat(Math.Round(((billPrice / dPrice) * 100), 0), " %");
                                                dt.Rows[i]["PercentVariance"] = Math.Round(((billPrice / dPrice) * 100), 0);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        dt.Rows[i]["Unit Price"] = objFirstItem.Price;
                                        dPrice = Convert.ToDouble(objFirstItem.Price) * Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[i][13]);
                                        dt.Rows[i]["Price"] = dPrice;

                                        double billPrice = Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[i][12]);
                                        dt.Rows[i]["Variance"] = (billPrice - dPrice);
                                        if (dPrice != 0)
                                        {
                                            //////dt.Rows[i]["PercentVariance"] = string.Concat(Math.Round(((billPrice / dPrice) * 100), 0), " %");
                                            dt.Rows[i]["PercentVariance"] = Math.Round(((billPrice / dPrice) * 100), 0);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            //////throw ex;
                        }
                    }

                    lstReturn = new List<Medicine>();
                    Medicine objMedicine = null;
                    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                                           try
            {
                FileInfo file = new FileInfo(pFileName);
                if (file.Exists)
                {
                    excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                    workbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(pFileName, 0, false, 5, "", "",
                    false, XlPlatform.xlWindows, "",
                    true, false, 0, true, false, false);

                    sheets = workbook.Sheets;

                    //check columns exist
                    foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet sheet in sheets)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(sheet.Name);
                        sheet.Select(Type.Missing);
                        /////////
                        lstSheetNames.Add(sheet.Name);
                        /////////
                        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(sheet);
                    }

                    newSheet = (Worksheet)sheets.Add(sheets[1], Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

                    newSheet.Name = "Updated";


                    /////////////////////////////////////////

                    string strConnection = string.Concat("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=", pFileName, ";Extended Properties=", "Excel 8.0;");
                    System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable("dtSheet");
                    try
                    {
                        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(strConnection))
                        {
                            using (OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + lstSheetNames[0] + "$]", conn))
                            {
                                conn.Open();
                                da.Fill(dt);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                    }

                    dt.Columns.Add("Unit Price", typeof(string));
                    dt.Columns.Add("Price", typeof(string));
                    dt.Columns.Add("Variance", typeof(string));
                    dt.Columns.Add("PercentVariance", typeof(string));

                    FDB objFDB = null;
                    string[] strFDB = File.ReadAllLines(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FDBFilePath"].ToString());
                    List<FDB> lstFDB = new List<FDB>();
                    foreach (string str in strFDB)
                    {
                        objFDB = new FDB();
                        objFDB.NDC = str.Substring(0, 11);
                        objFDB.PriceType = str.Substring(11, 2);
                        objFDB.Price = string.Concat(str.Substring(21, 6), ".", str.Substring(27, 5));
                        objFDB.Date = str.Substring(13, 8);
                        lstFDB.Add(objFDB);
                    }

                    double dPrice = 0;
                    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            string ndc = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i][7]);
                            List<FDB> objLst = (from item in lstFDB
                                                where item.NDC == ndc && item.PriceType == "09"
                                                orderby item.Date descending
                                                select item).ToList();
                            if (objLst != null)
                            {
                                FDB objFirstItem = objLst.FirstOrDefault();
                                if (objFirstItem != null)
                                {
                                    if (new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(objFirstItem.Date.Substring(0, 4)), Convert.ToInt32(objFirstItem.Date.Substring(4, 2)), Convert.ToInt32(objFirstItem.Date.Substring(6, 2))) > Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[i][6]))
                                    {
                                        if (objLst.Count > 1)
                                        {
                                            FDB objSecondItem = objLst[1];
                                            dt.Rows[i]["Unit Price"] = objSecondItem.Price;
                                            dPrice = Convert.ToDouble(objSecondItem.Price) * Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[i][13]);
                                            dt.Rows[i]["Price"] = dPrice;

                                            double billPrice = Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[i][12]);
                                            dt.Rows[i]["Variance"] = (billPrice - dPrice);
                                            if (dPrice != 0)
                                            {
                                                dt.Rows[i]["PercentVariance"] = string.Concat(Math.Round(((billPrice / dPrice) * 100), 0), " %");
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        dt.Rows[i]["Unit Price"] = objFirstItem.Price;
                                        dPrice = Convert.ToDouble(objFirstItem.Price) * Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[i][13]);
                                        dt.Rows[i]["Price"] = dPrice;

                                        double billPrice = Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[i][12]);
                                        dt.Rows[i]["Variance"] = (billPrice - dPrice);
                                        if (dPrice != 0)
                                        {
                                            dt.Rows[i]["PercentVariance"] = string.Concat(Math.Round(((billPrice / dPrice) * 100), 0), " %");
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            //////MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                        }
                    }


                    //////for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
                    //////{
                    //////    newSheet.Cells[1, i + 1] = dt.Columns[i].Caption;
                    //////    newSheet.Cells[1, i + 1].Font.Bold = true;
                    //////    //////newSheet.Cells[1, i + 1].Interior.Color = Color.FromArgb(191, 191, 191);
                    //////}

                    int rowCount = 1;

                    foreach (System.Data.DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        rowCount += 1;
                        for (int i = 1; i < dt.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
                        {
                                                           newSheet.Cells[rowCount, i] = dr[i - 1].ToString();

                        }
                    }

                    //////////////////////////////////////////

                    workbook.Save();
                    workbook.Close(null, null, null);
                    excelApp.Quit();

                    ////////////////////////////////

                    lstReturn = new List<Medicine>();
                    Medicine objMedicine = null;
                    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            objMedicine = new Medicine();
                            objMedicine.FacID = dt.Rows[i][0] != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i][0]) : "";
                            objMedicine.PatID = dt.Rows[i][1] != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i][1]) : "";
                            objMedicine.Patient = dt.Rows[i][2] != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i][2]) : "";
                            objMedicine.PriceCd = dt.Rows[i][3] != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i][3]) : "";
                            objMedicine.InvoiceGrp = dt.Rows[i][4] != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i][4]) : "";
                            objMedicine.RxNo = dt.Rows[i][5] != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i][5]) : "";
                            objMedicine.FillDate = dt.Rows[i][6] != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i][6]) : "";
                            objMedicine.NDC = dt.Rows[i][7] != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i][7]) : "";
                            objMedicine.Drug = dt.Rows[i][8] != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i][8]) : "";
                            objMedicine.BrandGen = dt.Rows[i][9] != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i][9]) : "";
                            objMedicine.RxOTC = dt.Rows[i][10] != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i][10]) : "";
                            objMedicine.FWBillDate = dt.Rows[i][11] != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i][11]) : "";
                            objMedicine.FWBillAmt = dt.Rows[i][12] != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i][12]) : "";
                            objMedicine.Quantity = dt.Rows[i][13] != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i][13]) : "";
                            objMedicine.UnitPrice = dt.Rows[i][14] != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i][14]) : "";
                            objMedicine.Price = dt.Rows[i][15] != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i][15]) : "";
                            objMedicine.Variance = dt.Rows[i][16] != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i][16]) : "";
                            objMedicine.PercentVariance = dt.Rows[i][17] != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i][17]) : "";

                            lstReturn.Add(objMedicine);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {

                        }
                    }

                                       }
            }
```

Comment: Don't you think you should tell us how  you read the Excel sheet? Or maybe show some more code?

Comment: here i have the service code that reads and write columns.

Comment: You should probably narrow that down a bit, since nobody is going to read all of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Interop is NOT supported in sever-scenarios (like ASP.NET, IIS, WCF, Windows Service etc.) by MS](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;q257757#kb2).**

There are many options to read/edit/create Excel files without Interop:

MS provides the free OpenXML SDK V 2.0 - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854%28office.14%29.aspx (XLSX only)

This can read+write MS Office files (including Excel).

Another free option see http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/OpenXML.aspx (XLSX only)

IF you need more like handling older Excel versions (like XLS, not only XLSX), rendering, creating PDFs, formulas etc. then there are different free and commercial libraries like [ClosedXML](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/) (free, XLSX  only), [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) (free, XLSX only), [Aspose.Cells](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.cells-for-.net/default.aspx), [SpreadsheetGear](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/), [LibXL](http://www.libxl.com/) and [Flexcel](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/flexcelnet.asp) etc.

Comment: I am having trouble finding the SDK 1. for the older excels.

Comment: @PinchasK AFAIK for the older Excels the only SDKs I know of are the commerical ones I listed at the end of my answer...